# Blocking network scanners

Tags: windows-server-2008

There is a network consisting of 50 staffs. 
Some staffs perform network scanning through Network Scan programs. 
Can I block Network Scan programs in my server so that users could not use? 
Server is Windows Server 2008, all PCs are connected to domain

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, assuming your network is under control and you have policies in place. Take your pick from any or all of the following.

- This can be done by application blacklisting or outbound firewall rules on the client. This would stop the traffic from ever being generated.
- You can also firewall your server such that only allowed applications are allowed for these users. The traffic would be generated but it would have nothing to connect to.
- You should also have an acceptable use policy in place that allows for anyone abusing the network to be easily terminated. Collect proof of wrongdoing, associate it with a user and work with a manager / hr.

Comment: Is there any firewall in Windows Server 2008 by default? Can I use it for allowing/disallowing users to use certain applications?

Comment: @ITEngineer yes there is and yes you can. The more granular you get the more complex it becomes but it is doable.

Comment: The challenge with Software Restrictions or AppLocker is that you'd have to compile a list of all the known executables that you want to block or compile a list of all the executables that you want to allow, which would be quite daunting and would probably require frequent changes as users find new executables to scan with that you need to block or as you install new user applications that you need to allow.

Comment: Even trying to use the firewall would be a challenge. A Program rule in the firewall to block the program requires you to know the path of the program that you want to block. I don't see that as being particularly easy or tenable long term. How will you know what program to block and where it's installed or running from on each computer?

Comment: @joeqwerty, yes I am agree with you, How will I know it? This is a problem

Comment: @TimBrigham, joeqwerty, what about services? Can I disable certain services in Windows Server so that users of domain could not use that particular service?

Comment: @joeqwerty I was thinking whitelisting the outbound traffic from the clients, at least to the server(s) in question. That would get around the need for knowing the paths.